# Returning nodes with specific relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a db of drugs and manufacturers and I want to find all manufacturers who have produced multiple drugs. How can I get only the manufacturers and the drugs they have produced?

I'm currently using

```
match (a:Brand), (c:Manufacturer) where size((c)-[:PRODUCED]->()) >1 return a,c;
```

which returns manufacturers with more than one drug produced but also all drugs, regardless of manufacturer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query uses the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/), `COLLECT`, to return a record for each manufacturer who makes multiple brands, along with a collection of those brands:

```
MATCH (m:Manufacturer)-[:PRODUCED]->(b:Brand)
WITH m, COLLECT(b) AS brands
WHERE SIZE(brands) > 1
RETURN m, brands;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you only need to select the manufacturers, like so:

```
MATCH (c:Manufacturer) WHERE size((c)-[:PRODUCED]->()) > 1 RETURN c;
```